# Knockout not binding Json to multiple Select

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am unable to bind json data to a select list using Knockout. What happens is the select list is created with an option for each of the json records but it does not bind any data to the list. Essentially it is a bunch of empty options. I can even see the data in the view model after applyBindings() via the console so I know the data is there. I am new to knockout so I may be missing something. Please help

```
var resources = [{"Resource":{"Id":1,"Name":"Bob"}},{"Resource":{"Id":2,"Name":"Jim"}}];

var viewModel = { resourceList: ko.observableArray(resources)}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: resourceList, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in your `resourceList` do not contain `Name` or `Id` properties, they contain a `Resource` object that does.

You'll either need to project each resource to those objects and bind to that:

```
var viewModel = {
    resourceList: ko.observableArray(resources),
    resourceListProjection: ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(this.resourceList(), function (o) {
            return o.Resource;
        });
    }, viewModel);
};
```

Or create accessor functions to get the appropriate properties.

```
<select multiple="multiple"
    data-bind="options: resourceList,
               optionsText: function (o) { return o.Resource.Name; },
               optionsValue: function (o) { return o.Resource.Id; }">
```